# Nested queries in BIML

Tags: sql-server, ssis, biml

I'm trying my hand at BIML and the path is full of trial and error.

I have to transfer data from fixed length flats files and I stored the metadata for my files and fields in two SQL Server tables: SourceTable and SourceColumn. So I have tried the following to generate the metadata for my fields:

```
<Tables>
<# Dim dtTables as DataTable = ExternalDataAccess.GetDataTable(staging.ConnectionString, "SELECT TableName FROM SourceTable")
for each dr as datarow In dtTables.Rows#>
<Table Name="<#= dr.item(0)#>" SchemaName="myDatabase.mySchema">
<Columns>
<# Dim dtColumns as DataTable = ExternalDataAccess.GetDataTable(staging.ConnectionString,"SELECT ColumnName FROM SourceColumn WHERE TableName = '+<#=dr.item(0)#>+'")
for each drColumn as datarow in dtColumns.Rows#>
<Column Name="<#= drColumn.Item(0) #>"></Column>
<#next#>
</Columns>
</Table>
<#next#>
</Tables>
```

Of course, BIML doesn't want me to concatenate `<#=dr.item(0)#>` (the table name) in the middle of the second query.

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you!

Simon.

Comment: I realize my question is more about embedding a nugget inside another nugget, which doesn't seem possible. Still, what's the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're inside the `<#` you are in "normal" coding space so you would have access to whatever variables are available

Change

```
Dim dtColumns as DataTable = ExternalDataAccess.GetDataTable(staging.ConnectionString,"SELECT ColumnName FROM SourceColumn WHERE TableName = '+<#=dr.item(0)#>+'")
```

to

```
Dim dtColumns as DataTable = ExternalDataAccess.GetDataTable(staging.ConnectionString,"SELECT ColumnName FROM SourceColumn WHERE TableName = '" & dr.item(0) & "'")
```

And yes to the future commenters, this could be risky if someone added sql injection into your table but if that's happened, you're already owned.

Comment: I'm kinda rusty so I had the feeling I was making a stupid mistake. Thanks for coming to my rescue again!